# 製品やライブラリの公式サイトからこのサイトを訪れた方へ

Tags: サポート, よくある質問, 質問の仕方

[Monaca](http://www.asial.co.jp/pressrelease/427) や [Bluemix](https://developer.ibm.com/bluemix/2015/04/15/bluemix-on-stack-overflow/) をはじめとして、様々な製品やライブラリ、フレームワークなどがサポートフォーラムとしてStackOverflowを案内していますが、このサイトではどんな質問に答えてくれますか？

[←FAQ目次に戻る](/q/1484)

Comment: サポートフォーラムとして利用したいベンダー向けの説明は[ヘルプセンター](http://ja.stackoverflow.com/help/product-support)にも書かれていますが、ここに案内されてきたユーザー向けに要約してみました。該当する質問にコメントするときにURLを貼って使えるかなという考えです。

Answer (score 12, accepted):

ここは様々な分野のプログラマーが技術的な質問・回答を交わすQ&Aサイトです。

例えば、以下のような質問はこのサイトに適しています。

- 作成したプログラムを実行すると××というエラーが出てしまうのはなぜ？
- プログラミング言語○○でこういう機能を実装するには？

ヘルプセンターの[「良い質問をするには?」](https://ja.stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) や [「どのような質問は避けるべきですか?」](https://ja.stackoverflow.com/help/dont-ask) もご覧ください。

一方で、このサイトは**公式のサポート・問い合わせ窓口ではありません。**

開発チームやサポートチームが見ているとは限りませんし、独自の情報網を持っているわけでもありません。したがって、以下のような質問はここに投稿しても解決しない可能性が高いです。

- 製品自体がうまく動かない、サービスが停止している、ログインできない
- バグを見つけた、追加してほしい機能がある、××の実装予定はいつか
- なぜこういう仕様になっているのか知りたい

また、開発者ダッシュボードの使い方、APIキーの取得方法、アプリの審査基準といったものも、Q&Aサイトでは扱いにくい質問です。あなたのアカウントがどういう状態なのかは第三者にはわかりませんし、仕様やルールの変更を全て把握しているわけでもありません。

このような場合は、公式のフォーラムが他にあればそちらに投稿していただくか、その製品の問い合わせ窓口を利用していただいたほうが、的確な回答が得られるかと思います。

参考： [製品サポートとしてこのサイトを使ってもよいですか？ - ヘルプ センター](https://ja.stackoverflow.com/help/product-support)